# Finding the first indices of the elements of one array in another

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
A=[3 4 5 6 7;1 0 3 5 9;1 8 10 11 12];

B=[1 0 5 5 9 ];
```

I want to find B in A, but like this:

- find first rowA of value 1 (from B)
- find first rowA of value 0 (from B)
- find first rowA of value 5 (from B)

I should have at the end `C=[2 2 1 2 2]`

```
for i = 1:length(B)
    index(i) = find(A(:,i) == B(i),1)
end

error: Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.
```

Comment: sorry! I tried this:                                                                                                    for i  = 1:length(B)
    index(i) = find(A(:,i) == B(i),1)
    end    error:Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct. You must initialize the `index`-variable:

```
index = zeros(1,size(A,2));
for i = 1:length(B)
    index(i) = find(A(:,i) == B(i),1);
end
index

index =
     2     2     1     2     2
```